# List size returns 0 after adding object

Tags: java, android, arraylist, retrofit, okhttp

Can anybody help me figure out this (to me) weird bug. I have been looking at it for hours and still cannot figure it out, I cannot find anything alike on the web aswell.

I am using retrofit2 and OkHttp3 to make some GET API calls. Somehow after I get an response (which is Successful && the body does contain what is has to) and I try to add it to the list, at the end of the loop the list size returns 0.

```
final List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();

final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

...

dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                API someAPI = new API();

                for (int i = 0; i < listWithIds.size(); i++) {
                    Call<Object> call = someAPI.getObject(listWithIds.get(i).getId());
                    final int finalI = i;
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {

                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                                objectList.add(response.body());

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Callback is asynchronous, are you checking list size outside queue or in the callback?

Comment: `List` returns size 0 only if its size 0. So, you need to check whether `add` was called.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `finalI` variable? And why not use enhanced for-loop?

Comment: @lubilis I am checking it outside the queue.

Comment: @SinaMadani I have cleared out some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queue is asynchronous, you're checking list size inside the loop but outside queue, it's too early. List size is still zero because you're adding object in the callback response.

Try to check list size inside callback delegate.